# android studio request permissions error (kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, android-studio-3.0

i tried to set request 5 permissions check in my code

Of course I added all five to the manifest.
and i also tried to deleted the app and reinstalled it.

but it doesnt ask permissions at all

this is my root class

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    (...)

       if (checkAndRequestPermissions()) {

            Handler().postDelayed({

                val intent = Intent(this, ActivityMain::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)

            }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT.toLong())
        }
```

and checkAndRequestPermissions() method

```
 fun checkAndRequestPermissions(): Boolean {

        val internetP = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.INTERNET)
        val networkP = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE)
        val wifiP = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE)
        val changeWifiP = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE)
        val notifiacationP = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY)


        val listPermissionsNeeded = ArrayList<String>()

        if (internetP != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.INTERNET)
        }
        if (networkP != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE)
        }
        if (wifiP != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE)
        }
        if (changeWifiP != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE)
        }
        if (notifiacationP != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY)
        }
        if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, listPermissionsNeeded.toTypedArray(), REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS)
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
```

```
 if (checkAndRequestPermissions()) {
```

'checkAndRequstPermissions() ' value is always true

I think there's a problem here.

```
 if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
```

even if listPersmissionsNeeded value is '0' it keep returning true, never going inside

I referred to this site ->

https://demonuts.com/kotlin-runtime-permissions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the above mentioned permissions do not require runtime permission check and approval. These permissions are only to be mentioned in the Manifest file.

That's why function `checkAndRequestPermissions()` is always returning true.

See this link

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview.html#normal-dangerous

Hope this helps. Happy Coding :)

Comment: thank you v very much! i haven't think about that way!

Answer (score 0):

Its seems all permission are already given.Its not problem in the code.

Because these are 
[Normal permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview.html#normal-dangerous)  so no need to handle run time checker.

[dangerous permissions and permission groups](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview.html#normal-dangerous) only required runtime permissions handlers.